# Unable to access docker container from browser

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, pytest, integration-testing

I wrote a ChatOps bot for the open source collaboration tool Mattermost using [this framework](https://github.com/attzonko/mmpy_bot). Now I want to write some integration tests and run them. When I follow the [steps](https://github.com/attzonko/mmpy_bot/tree/main/tests/integration_tests) to run the integration tests from their project, they won't succeed. I used the command `pytest --capture=no --log-cli-level=DEBUG .` to run the integration tests.

It fails because `localhost:8065` is not available yet after running the command `docker-compose up -d`. Anybody knows what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you on Linux, Mac, or Windows?  I think `network_mode: host` [only works on Linux](https://docs.docker.com/network/host/).

Try to edit the `docker-compose.yml` file, remove the network mode "host", and [add a port mapping](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/), something like this:

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  app:
    container_name: "mattermost-bot-test"
    build: .
    command: ./mm/docker-entry.sh
    ports:
      - "8065:8065"
    extra_hosts:
      - "dockerhost:127.0.0.1"
```

Comment: Thanks, the docker container is reachable now. However their integration tests keep failing, maybe there's something wrong in the Python code.